Receiving confusing 429 Resource Exhausted Error with Gemini Vertex AI
I am using Vertex Gemini via NodeJs running in a Cloud Run service for a chatbot application. I am sending multimodal requests (PDFs mostly) and requesting a streaming response. Intermittently, I am receiving a 429 error similar to the following:
GoogleGenerativeAIError: [VertexAI.GoogleGenerativeAIError]: Failed to parse final chunk of stream: {
 "error": {
 "code": 429,
 "message": "Quota exceeded.
Consumer:911923099736\nMetric:dlp.googleapis.com/quota_tokens_regional
Allowed:80000\nLocation:us-central1
Request more:https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/dlp.googleapis.com/quotas?project=911923099736"exceeded.

Consumer:911923099736Metric:dlp.googleapis.com/quota_tokens_regional Allowed:80000Location:us-central1

Request more:https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/dlp.googleapis.com/quotas?project=911923099736

This is telling me the error is with a DLP API, which shouldn't be the case because 1) I have not enabled that API and 2) I am using Vertex AI only for this use case.
I also checked my Vertex AI quotas in the us-central1 region and none of them are close to being reached.
Furthermore, the project ID listed, 911923099736, is not a project ID I have in my organization (maybe it's one in the Google tenant?).
Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you

Can you share the invoked API (or the piece of code that call the API)?

This equals too many requests per second. Add a delay

You may request here for a higher quota value for the encountered error message quota exceeded.
If you find that you can't request an adjustment from the console, request the increase from Cloud Customer Care you may ask here as well your confusion why you have the project ID which is not owned by your organization.
Cloud Quotas adjustment requests are subject to review. If your quota adjustment request requires review, you receive an email acknowledging receipt of your request. If you need further assistance, respond to the email. After reviewing your request, you receive an email notification indicating whether your request was approved.
